# How can we set a UIView as a mask of another UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4, cagradientlayer

I have

1. gradientView it's just a gradient view  I have
2. a view containerView with an anImageView and aUILabel

Now when I try to

```
gradientView.mask = containerView
```

**it does not show anything   however when I do**

```
gradientView.mask = anImageView
```

or

```
gradientView.mask = aUILabel
```

It apply mask nicely.
Is there a way I can achieve

```
gradientView.mask = containerView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView` and `UILabel` both have intrinsic content size, but not `UIView`. Mask of a view has to have a frame set properly. Make sure that the `containerView.frame` is set:

```
containerView.frame = gradientView.bounds
```

Also, make sure that `containerView.backgroundColor` is set to `UIColor.clear`.

Comment: I'd just like to add another thing the view's background color should be clearColor

Comment: @AsadullahAli so it didn't work? or what do you mean that the view's background color should be clearColor?

Comment: It's half correct. I had to add containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

Comment: @AsadullahAli Oh, ok, I'll update the answer.. I expected that `containerView`'s backgroundColor is clearColor, since that is the default backgroundColor of a `UIView`

Comment: When we add it from storyboard the default color is white which caused me hours of time waste so it would be good for others to know.

Comment: @AsadullahAli yeah, of course, you are right. I never use storyboards, so didn't occur to me.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is even if the view has a frame set in storyboard it still needs frame to be set again in the code